# Kerberos v5: SPN as a client in AS_REQ

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Is it possible to use service principal name, e.g. HTTP/something.com@REALM.COM (not user principal name) as a client in AS_REQ to MS Active Directory to get TGT?
What principal type should be in request in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported by Microsoft AD, according to what was determined by Samba AD developers (Samba tries to mimic Microsoft AD as closely as possible):

1. It was enabled in Samba at one point:
   commit [20dc68050df7b1b0c9d06f8251183a0a6283fcaf](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commit;h=20dc68050df7b1b0c9d06f8251183a0a6283fcaf)
2. There was a mailing list thread about whether it matches Windows AD DC behavior:
    https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2017-November/123760.html,
    https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2017-November/123803.html,
    https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2017-November/124101.html
3. Afterwards, using SPNs was disabled again in Samba:
   commit [a6182bd9512e6c78cfd2127790419418ab776be9](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commit;h=a6182bd9512e6c78cfd2127790419418ab776be9)

On the other hand, non-AD environments don't really distinguish between the two and generally accept KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL even if the client looks like a service.